# Adding arrow heads to a line in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding a line in code in WPF between two ellipses which works fine. I now need to add a triangle as an arrow head indicator at the top and bottom of my line. My problem is that I do not know the mathematical equation to ensure that the triangle is exactly over the top of my line and facing the correct direction. I have attached a image showing the issue, any help would be greatly received.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us code which draws those lines/triangles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a `Line` element, you would calculate the angle of its direction (clockwise from north) by

```
var dx = line.X2 - line.X1;
var dy = line.Y2 - line.Y1;
var angle = 180 * (1 - Math.Atan2(dx, dy) / Math.PI);
```

or

```
var angle = Vector.AngleBetween(new Vector(0, -1), new Vector(dx, dy));
```

You could use that angle for the `Angle` property of a RotateTransform.

---

An example:

```
<Line x:Name="line" X1="100" Y1="100" X2="200" Y2="200"
        Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3"/>

<Path Fill="Red">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M0,10 L10,30 -10,30Z">
            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotation"/>
                    <TranslateTransform
                        X="{Binding ElementName=line, Path=X2}"
                        Y="{Binding ElementName=line, Path=Y2}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </PathGeometry.Transform>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

with this code behind:

```
rotation.Angle = angle;
```